# How I can convert -keep @interface * proguard configuration to ant?

Tags: java, proguard

How can I use pro guard `-keep @interface *` in an ant project build.xml?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Can you explain more precisly what is your problem ?

Comment: I am new to proguard configuration, I have issue with json annotations in some bean classes, so I want to keep all annotations. I found -keep @interface *  when I search for the solution, but here I want to know how to use the same thing with ant build.xml?